# Time and date picker in spring mvc

Tags: date, time, picker

I'm using spring mvc and need a calendar or date and time picker into my jsp.

My question is what is best to do, use an existing date picker in jquery or write own calendar in java ?

And I need to save date and time when a user is choosing(booking) a date and time, how do I do that in this case?

I want to do something like this: 
http://codecanyon.net/item/booking-calendar-pro-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/244645

Is possible to do such a calendar in jsp ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try DHTMLX JavaPlanner with simple load and save logic http://javaplanner.com/

This [booking tutorial in Spring MVC](http://javaplanner.com/blog/spring-mvc-booking-system-tutorial/) can also be helpful.